# Error in CAML query

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio, caml-query, visual-web-part

Have I written the below CAML query correctly? Am I missing anything? I am encountering an error on below line of code.

```
SPQuery spQuery = new SPQuery();
spQuery.Query = "<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Flag'/><Value Type='Text'>" + "1" + "</Value></Eq>" + "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Connection Type'/><Value Type='Text'>" + "Active Directory" + "</Value></Eq></And></Where>";
```

The error reads...

> One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list
>   settings page to delete these fields

"

Comment: Please check the internal names of the columns. Please check internal name of `connection type`. Sometimes space between column names occurs this type of issues. Also check their column types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the columns with spaces have the space represented in Unicode as `_x0020_`, try the following line:

```
spQuery.Query = "<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Flag'/><Value Type='Text'>" + "1" + "</Value></Eq>" + "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Connection_x002_Type'/><Value Type='Text'>" + "Active Directory" + "</Value></Eq></And></Where>";
```

In order to get the internal name of a column:

1. Go into List Settings or the site columns list in site settings.
2. Click on the column you want the internal name for.
3. Look at the URL for `Field=<Column Name>`

It should be at the end of the URL and will give you the exact internal name for your column.

Comment: take a look at robocaml.codeplex.com.

Answer (score 2):

The `<FieldRef Name='Connection Type'>` is incorrect. If you used a space when creating this column then the internal name is `Connection_x0020_Type`

Comment: Thanks All. Yes the mistake was in the Field Name. The correct field name is "Connection_x0020_Type"